# "Did you ever go?" or "Have you ever been?"

Tags: past-tense, questions, present-tense, perfect-constructions

Which answers would you pick as correct?

Is it possible that both (*Did you ever go/ Have you ever been?*) are correct?

> A: France is the best country I've ever been.
> *Did you ever go/ Have you ever been?*
> B: Yes, I *have been / went* two years ago

Answer (score 1):

"Have you ever been" is definitely better for this case.

"Did you ever go" implies a that the person being asked was supposed to "go".  For example, "Did you ever go the grocery store like I asked?"

Comment: Not necessarily. I myself would use _have you ever_, but _did you ever_ is a possible alternative (there's a song with the refrain "Did you ever see such a funny thing before?")

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting. I should also add that, in the mid-west states, it is often that we favor saying "Did you ever go..." instead of "have you ever been." Personally, I feel that both sentences are correct, but "Have you ever been" sounds more elegant and proper.